# Mini-Max Sum In JavaScript - How to Get the Minimum Sum And Maximum Sum of 4 Elements in a 5-Element Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

[Link to HackerRank Challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem?utm_campaign=challenge-recommendation&utm_medium=email&utm_source=24-hour-campaign)

My idea is to loop through the array and sum all elements in the array except for one element each time, then find the smallest sum and the largest sum.

I know that `.splice()` can remove any element from an array. But currently, with my code, it's only removing one element from the array **once**. I.e. this is only giving me one chunk:

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {

  let smallestSum = 0;
  let largestSum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let chunk = arr.splice(1);
    console.log(chunk);
    if (chunk > largestSum) largestSum = chunk;
    if (chunk < smallestSum) smallestSum = chunk;
  }
  return (smallestSum, largestSum);
}
```

I need to remove one element from the array **every time** while looping, then get the max and min sums from that array.

So for given array of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

I should get the following possible "chunks":

`[2, 3, 4, 5]`, `[1, 3, 4, 5]`, `[1, 2, 4, 5]`, `[1, 2, 3, 5]`, `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

The chunk with the highest sum is `[2, 3, 4, 5]`

And the chunk with the smallest sum is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

How can I adjust my code to get all of the possible 4-digit arrays within the given array so that I can compare their sums, still using a for-loop? Or if not with a for-loop, what else would you suggest?

**EDIT**: Now using `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` to get the smallest and largest elements in the array. Then using `.filter()` to remove those elements in order to create new arrays. Then getting the sums of those arrays.

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {

  let smallest = Math.min(...arr);
  let largest = Math.max(...arr);

  let smallestArray = arr.filter(element => element !== largest);
  let largestArray = arr.filter(element => element !== smallest);

  let sumOfSmallestArray = 0;
  let sumOfLargestArray = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < smallestArray.length; i++) {
    sumOfSmallestArray += smallestArray[i];
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < largestArray.length; i++) {
    sumOfLargestArray += largestArray[i];
  }

  return ([sumOfSmallestArray, sumOfLargestArray]).toString();
}
```

But even though it works in my console, it doesn't work in HackerRank.

Comment: Observation: the chunk with the largest sum is the chunk without the smallest element, and the chunk with the smallest sum is the chunk without the largest element. It seems like this problem is really just a different form of "find the largest and smallest elements of an array".

Comment: As suggested by @p.s.w.g on the similar lines. Sort your array first, then just take out the first element and add for max sum and for min takeout the last number. No looping required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is to sort that array first, then the minimum will be the first element and the maximum will be the last, hence if you want to get the minimum set, it will be the array without the highest value (last element) and if you want to get the maximum set it will be the array without the lowest value (first element).

```js
let data = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5];

// sort first
data = data.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  
// to get the sets only
let maxSet = data.slice(1);
let minSet = data.slice(0, -1);

console.log(minSet, maxSet);

// to get just the max/min value
const sum = data.reduce((a, total) => a + total, 0);
console.log(sum - data[data.length - 1], sum - data[0]);
```

Comment: Using `.sort()` is a really good idea - thank you. This works in HackerRank when `console.log(minSet, maxSet);` is commented out.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: One thing I'm noticing about `.sort()` is that it doesn't work for arrays that are passed into a function: https://codepen.io/AnonymousName/pen/LvQwJv?editors=1112. Looks like you either have to declare your array within the function (as you did in your answer) or use a callback function: https://codepen.io/HappyHands31/pen/axqeKR?editors=1112

Comment: That's not the problem. The default sort does the sorting based on strings, so that's why you are getting wrong sorts for integers.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the min and max values of the array and filter the array by taking not min or max value once.

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    min = Math.min(...data),
    max = Math.max(...data),
    dataMin = data.filter(v => v !== min || !(min = -Infinity)),
    dataMax = data.filter(v => v !== max || !(max = Infinity));

console.log(...dataMin);
console.log(...dataMax);
```

A more classical approach

```js
function minMax(array) {
    var min = array[0],
        max = array[0],
        sum = array[0],
        i, v;
    
    for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        v = array[i];
        sum += v;
        if (v > max) max = v;
        if (v < min) min = v;
    }
    console.log(sum - min, sum - max);
}

minMax([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Comment: I think this solution makes the most sense, but I don't understand `.filter(v => v !== min || !(min = -Infinity)),`. Can you explain that please? Maybe the arrow notation is throwing me off. Here's a JS Fiddle trying to follow your logic: https://jsfiddle.net/hyp6m1eu/

Comment: Just need to learn how to subtract `min` from `data` to find the `largestArray`, and subtract `max` from `data` to find the `smallestArray`.

Comment: the assignment is to prevent to exclude the value more than once, if you have a value more than one time. the assigned value is either the possible min or max value.

Comment: Can you take a look at the edit that I made to my original post, please? Since I can get the `smallest` and `largest` items from the array using `Math.min()` and `Math.max()`, how can I then subtract those elements from the array to create two new arrays? `smallestArray` and `largestArray`? Then I can return the sum of the elements of those two new arrays.

Comment: This works in my console, as does my edited code above, but neither work in HackerRank, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

The HackerRank challenge just asks for the sums of the, so you can make one pass through the array to calculate 3 facts:

- Maximum element (`a`)
- Minimum element (`b`)
- Total sum of all elements (`c`)

The sum of the smallest chunk will be `c - a` and the sum of the largest will be `c - b`.

Here's a one-liner solution using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var [a, b, c] = arr.reduce(([a, b, c], x) => [a > x ? a : x, b < x ? b : x, c + x], [NaN, NaN, 0]);
console.log(c - a, c - b);
```

Note: the `NaN`'s are just here to force the initial conditions (`a > x`/`b < x` to be false)

Comment: Given your original comment and logic, can't I find the lowest element in the array using `Math.min()` and highest element in the array using `Math.max()`? Then how can I subtract `lowest` and `highest` from the array to get the `smallestArray` and `largestArray`? (see my edit).

Comment: @HappyHands31 Yes, that's exactly what I was hinting at with the original comment. That's how Nina Scholz's answer works, and it's a perfectly good solution. After reading through the HackerRank challenge though, I realized it's not *required* that you figure out what that chunk is, only what the sum is. You don't actually have to compute these intermediate arrays if you just work off the sums instead. My answer doesn't technically address the original question, I'm just proposing an alternate approach to the challenge.

Comment: @HappyHands31 consider input `[1, 1, 3, 5, 5]`, your filter rules out two 1, and two 5, thus the fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can `sort` the array and for `min` take first four and add them and for `max` take last four and add them

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let minAndMax = (arr) => {
  arr = arr.sort((a,b) => a - b)
  let op = {}

  op.minArr = arr.slice(0,4)
  op.min = op.minArr.reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0)
  
  op.maxArr =  arr.slice(arr.length-4,) 
  op.max = op.maxArr.reduce((a,b) => a + b ,0)
  return op
}


console.log(minAndMax(arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution traverses the slice indexes, calculates the sum and when a maximum is found, it is put into result. Finally result is parsed:

```
var arr = [4, 8, 2, 6, 12];
var ln = arr.length;
var maxSum = undefined;
var result = "";
for (var splIndex = 0; splIndex < ln; splIndex++) {
    var item = arr.splice(splIndex, 1);
    var sum = 0;
    for (var it of arr) sum += it;
    if ((maxSum === undefined) || (maxSum < sum)) {
        maxSum = sum;
        result = JSON.stringify(arr);
    }
    arr.splice(splIndex, 0, item[0]);
}
console.log(JSON.parse(result));
```

EDIT

A simpler solution, of course is to find the minimum and calculate the sum without it.

Answer (score 1):

The following function works:

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    var _arr = arr.sort((a, b) = > a - b)
    var minVals = _arr.slice(0, 4)
    var maxVals = _arr.slice(1)
    const arrSum = __arr = > __arr.reduce((a, b) = > a + b, 0)
    var minSum = arrSum(minVals)
    var maxSum = arrSum(maxVals)
    console.log(minSum, maxSum)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [15 ,12, 33, 25, 4];
//sort array
const arrSort = arr.sort((a,b)=> a-b );
console.log(arrSort);
//get values and sum 
var max = arrSort.filter(value => value < Math.max(...arrSort)).reduce((ac,at)=>{
    ac += at;
    return ac; 
},0);
var min = arrSort.filter(value => value > Math.min(...arrSort)).reduce((ac,at)=>{
    ac += at;
    return ac; 
},0);
console.log(max);
console.log(min);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
let minValue, maxValue
const ascendingArray = arr.sort((a,b) => a - b)

const smallestNumber = ascendingArray[0]
const biggestNumber = ascendingArray[ascendingArray.length -1]

if(smallestNumber !== biggestNumber){

    const biggestArray = arr.filter((number) => {
        return number !== smallestNumber
     })

     const smallestArray = arr.filter((number) => {
         return number !== biggestNumber
      })

     minValue = smallestArray.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
     maxValue = biggestArray.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
     console.log(minValue, maxValue);
}
else{
    const arraySliced = arr.slice(0, 4)

    const value = arraySliced.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
    console.log(value, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    var soma = 0
    let t = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        soma += arr[i]
        max = soma - arr[i]
    }
    let min = soma - arr[0]
    return max + ' ' + min
}

console.log(miniMaxSum([7, 69, 2, 221, 8974]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cleaner approach to solving this problem.

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
   let min, max, sum, arrMin, arrMax; // declare variables
   min = Math.min(...arr) // gets the smallest value from the arr
   max = Math.max(...arr) // gets the largest number from the arr
   sum = arr.reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0); // reduce used to add all values in arr
   arrMin = sum - max; // excludes the largest value 
   arrMax = sum - min; // excludes the smallest value
   console.log(arrMin+' '+arrMax) // output
}
```

Answer (score 1):

easy solution

```js
const miniMax = arr => {
    let min = arr[0];
    let max = arr[0];

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] <= min) {
            min = arr[i];
        }
        if (arr[i] >= max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }

    let sum = arr.reduce((acc,curr) => acc + curr);

    console.log(sum - max, sum - min);  
}

miniMax([5,5,5,5,5]); 
// result : 20 20

miniMax([1,2,3,4,5]); 
// result : 10 14
```

Answer (score 0):

I get Answer in very Simple way

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
let minval=arr[0];
let maxval=0;
let totalSum=0;
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if (arr[i]>maxval){
        maxval=arr[i];
    }
    if (arr[i]<minval){
        minval=arr[i];
    }
    totalSum=totalSum+arr[i];
    
}

let minsum=totalSum - maxval;
let maxsum=totalSum - minval;

console.log( minsum,maxsum);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use build `Math` methods to find max and min:

```js
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    const min = Math.min(...arr);
    const max = Math.max(...arr);
    const sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    console.log(sum - max, sum - min);
}
```